# Prove that if $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\textbf{a})\neq 0$ then $\textbf{a}$ cannot be extrimum of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ in $C^2$ and harmonic. If $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\textbf{a})\neq 0$ then $\textbf{a}$ cannot be  extrimum of $f$

i am not getting any idea..can someone help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is harmonic, then the trace of the Hessian matrix is zero. The trace is equal to the sum of the two eigenvalues, which are real. Since the Hessian is not zero at $a$, it must have a non-zero eigenvalue. Both properties together imply that the Hessian has one negative eigenvalue and one positive eigenvalue.

Comment: Don't mention eigenvalues. Use the fact that the sum of the diagonal entries is zero.

Comment: @TedShifrin I cannot imagine which argument you have in mind. Arguing using eigenvalue seems to be the simplest way imho.

Comment: At an extremum, the second-order partials $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ have the same sign.

Comment: Both can be zero. So still an extra argument is needed.

Comment: Silly. Neither can be zero given the hypothesis of the problem.

Comment: Please write your own answer instead of calling people silly.

Comment: I interpreted the assumption as Hessian at $a$ is non-zero. Not $f_{xx}(a)\ne0$.